# convert dictonay in to list in python, Dictonary has multiple value in single key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get the values of the key. but issue is the key has multiple values. I want all the values in normal array/list:
here is my code:

```
dict={"Data": ["john", "vincin","tenzin"]}
dictlist=[]
for key, value in dict.items():
    temp = [value]
    dictlist.append(temp)
print(dictlist[0])
```

output:

```
[['john', 'vincin', 'tenzin']]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Expected result like this(normal list):

```
dictlist[0]="john"
dictlist[1]="vincin"
dictlist[2]="tenzin"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over the items in your list and append them individually to dictlist

```
dict={"Data": ["john", "vincin","tenzin"]}
dictlist=[]
for key, value in dict.items():
    for item in value:
        dictlist.append(item)
print(dictlist)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RoachLod

Answer (score 2):

use `extend()` which will extend list instead of `append()` which appends another list as item shown below:

```
dictlist.extend(temp)
```

updated code:

```
dict={"Data": ["john", "vincin","tenzin"]}
dictlist=[]
for key, value in dict.items():
    temp = [value]
    dictlist.extend(temp)

print(dictlist[0])
```

output:

```
['john', 'vincin', 'tenzin']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
dict={"Data": ["john", "vincin","tenzin"]}
dictlist=[]
for key, value in dict.items():
    dictlist.extend(value)
print(dictlist[0])
```

Note 1: don't use keyword `dict` as variable name

Note 2: this is even more concise: `dictlist = sum(dict.values(),[])`

Answer (score 0):

You could also just take the value from the dict, as it is already a list:

```
dict={"Data": ["john", "vincin","tenzin"]}
dictlist = dict['Data']

print(dictlist)
```

Gives:

```
  ['john', 'vincin', 'tenzin']
```